# How to compare text with a command word

Tags: batch-file, text

My overall objective with this batch file is to run through a .txt file and grab all lines after `Th-:  -2.000000   Th+:  -0.160000   - In Limits` (This is the limits for the tests always the same data comes directly after) and stop ac the end of the test "PASS" or "FAIL". as of now I have this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set flag = N
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do 
(
    set temp=%%a
    echo !flag!
    if "%%a" == "Pass\par" set flag=N
    if !flag! == Y  echo. %%a >> output.txt
    if "%%a" == "Th-:  -2.000000   Th+:  -0.160000   - In Limits\par" set flag=Y
)
pause
```

This sets a flag = N and will not write a line unless the flag = Y. This flag becomes high after the given line. My problem is that inside the "" to turn the flag high there is a '+' and 'In' which are keywords in batch, how would I go about commenting these out to include them in the text?

Any other suggestions for my code are much appreciated.

EDIT-- the text file appears as follows:

```
Th-:  -2.000000   Th+:  -0.160000   - In Limits

Die 1  :  -0.205359   Pass 

Die 2  :  -0.210690   Pass 

Die 3  :  -0.215712   Pass 

Die 4  :  -3.458495   Fail 

Die 5  :  -0.210452   Pass 

FAIL
```

I am trying to move solely the middle lines into another text file

Comment: why not use the unix command `diff`  ?

Comment: I thought that `diff` was for comparing files, I am writing these values into a blank text doc

Comment: yes ok sorry I missunderstand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that's what you want, but I will contribute a script that can help you, it creates 3 ​​variables with the contents of the file, 1 variable contains the entire content of the file. Txt, other variable contains all the content that is BEFORE the text you specify, and another variable contains all the content that is AFTER the text you specify.

```
@echo off
@break off
@title How to compare text with a command word - D3F4ULT
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM CRLF = Breakline Trick in Batch | P.S: Is need two breaklines between caret char and next command, don't remove the two breaklines

set CRLF=^


REM Start of Script
set "InputContentsAll="
set "InputContentsBefore="
set "InputContentsAfter="

set "FLAG=N"

for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ( "input.txt" ) do (
  set "InputContentsAll=!InputContentsAll!!CRLF!%%~a"
  if "%%~a" EQU "Th-: -2.000000 Th+: -0.160000 - In Limits" (
    set "FLAG=Y"
  ) else (
    if /I "!FLAG!" EQU "N" (
      if not defined InputContentsBefore (
        set "InputContentsBefore=%%~a"
      ) else (
        set "InputContentsBefore=!InputContentsBefore!!CRLF!%%~a"
      )
    ) else if /I "!FLAG!" EQU "Y" (
      if not defined InputContentsAfter (
        set "InputContentsAfter=%%~a"
      ) else (
        set "InputContentsAfter=!InputContentsAfter!!CRLF!%%~a"
      )
    )
  )
)

:: Variable InputContentsBefore = Before of "Th-: -2.000000 Th+: -0.160000 - In Limits"
:: Variable InputContentsAfter  = After  of "Th-: -2.000000 Th+: -0.160000 - In Limits"
:: Variable InputContentsAll    = All Contents of file input.txt

:: echo !InputContentsBefore!
:: echo !InputContentsAfter!
:: echo !InputContentsAfter!

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set flag=N
for /f "delims=" %%a in (q20686770.txt) do (
 IF NOT DEFINED flag ECHO %%a >>output.txt
 IF "%%a"=="PASS" SET flag=N
 IF "%%a"=="FAIL" SET flag=N
 if "%%a"=="Th-:  -2.000000   Th+:  -0.160000   - In Limits" set "flag="
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you.

Notes: I changed the input filename to `q20686770.txt` for my testing - you would need to change it back.

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

`TEMP` and `TMP` are special variablenames which specify the location of a temporary-files directory. Best not to change them as unexpected results may ensue.

"\par" is a literal text string - the `\` is rarely used as a regex escape character in batch - certainly not in an `if` statement.

Unfortunately, telling us `how` your code that doesn't work isn't very useful in communicating `what` it is supposed to do. There's no indication of what you intend to output. For istance, you don't say whether the final "PASS/FAIL" line is to be output, or whether the spacing is required.

To `NOT` output the final "PASS/FAIL", simply move the `if not defined` line after the `if..fail..` line.

The output will be `APPENDED` to any existing `output.txt`. If you want to create a new `output.txt` then you'd need to delete it at the start of your batch. To do this, simply insert a new line

```
del output.txt 2>nul
```

somewhere before the `FOR...` line. There **ARE** other ways to do this, but that way makes the least changes (and hence is easier to explain.) The line deletes the file, obviously, but also suppresses any error message if the file does not exist.